# Issue , Only last row gets updated

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uiprogressview

I am trying to create a `UIPickerView` inside `UITableViewCell`, and it works fine.
I have set the tag for `UIProgressView` as `indexPath.row`. Currently i have 3 rows
i am using this `UIProgressView` when downloading a file using `NSURLConnection`

When `NSURLConnection` calls the `connection:didReceiveData:` method, i try to update the progress by matching the `indexPath.row`, But, i am not sure why the last row only gets updated

Please let me know

```
- (void)download:(NSString*)rowId
{
    NSURL *url;

    if ([rowId intValue] == 0 ){
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.29/iphone/video/video_10.mov"];
    }
    else if ([rowId intValue]  == 1){
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.29/iphone/video/video_10.mov"];
    }
    else if ([rowId intValue]  == 2){
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.29/iphone/video/video_10.mov"];
    }



    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    connection = nil;

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)recievedData {
    if (data==nil) {
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
    }
    [data appendData:recievedData];
    NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[data length]];
    float progress = [resourceLength floatValue] / [self.filesize floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%d inside ",myId);
    UIProgressView* downPreView = (UIProgressView*)[self.view viewWithTag:myId];
    downPreView.progress = progress;

 }


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DownloadingCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    self.progressView = [[[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,70,170,15)]autorelease];
    [self.progressView setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    self.progressView.tag = indexPath.row;
    self.progressView.progress = 0.0f;
    myId = indexPath.row;
    NSString *aid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myId];

    NSLog(@"%@",aid);






    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.progressView];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(download:) withObject:aid waitUntilDone:NO];


    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Beautiful Dreamer";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"David Lehman";
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"download_poem_icon.png"];

    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Friends a Friendship";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Denise Levertov";

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"download_poem_icon.png"];

    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Love and Friendship";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Dorianne Laux";
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"download_poem_icon.png"];

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think The problem is: u have written : [self.view viewwithTag:] instruction.

Comment: But you should get the progressbar object accrding to the cell by: [cell.contentView viewWithTag:]. And also u should access the cell also.

Comment: @Simha.hb: thanks for the reply...actually when i print myId value it always shows as 2( so the last row)why is that showing  2 always?actually it has to be first 0,1,and then 2.pls let me know

Comment: Why you initialized always myId = 1; in cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: sorry that was a typo . fixed now

Comment: You can ask me in our chat room if you have any query at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8469/room-for-casual-chat

Comment: You should put `addSubview:` and all allocation object inside `cell==nil` statement. otherwise, you have a big leak there. plus you are not releasing `UIProgressView`

Answer (score 2):

**Try to create custom class like below:**

```
@protocol CustomConnectionDelegate

- (void)connection:(CustomConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)recievedData;

@end
@interface CustomConnection:NSURLConnection
{
    int myId;
    id<CustomConnectionDelegate>myDelegate;
}
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) int myId;
@property(nonatomic, retain) id<CustomConnectionDelegate>myDelegate;
```

.

```
@implementation CustomConnection
@synthesize myDelegate, myId;

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate WithRowId:(int)rowId
{
    self.myDelegate = delegate;
    myId = rowId;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)recievedData{
    [self.delegate connection:self didReceiveData:recievedData];
}
```